# CSS pseudo-classes and :disabled:valid selector

Tags: html, css

I want to apply some styles based on my input conditions. I don't want to use any additional classes and looking for a CSS only solution.

The problem is when I trying to use this selectors

```
:disabled:valid
:disabled:invalid
```

it just won't work. Any ideas?

Thank you for your time!

```css
input:disabled + span {
  color: gray;
}

input:valid + span, input:disabled:valid + span {
  color: green;
}

input:invalid + span, input:disabled:invalid + span {
  color: red;
}

fieldset {
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
}

fieldset > div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

button:first-child {
   margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <fieldset>
    <div>
      <label>First name</label>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Stephan" required>
      <span>Valid</span>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <label>Last name</label>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" required>
      <span>Invalid</span>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>

<div>
  <button onclick="document.querySelector('fieldset').disabled = true">Send</button>
  <button onclick="document.querySelector('fieldset').disabled = false">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If it is disabled then (a) It won't be submitted and (b) the user can't change it … so "valid" is meaningless.

Comment: @Quentin the spec disagrees: https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/forms.html#:~:text=even%20when%20the%20element%20is%20disabled "An element can still suffer from these states even when the element is disabled; thus these states can be represented in the DOM even if validating the form during submission wouldn't indicate a problem to the user."

Comment: @JonHieb — That's an out of date version of the spec. I can't find any similar language in the current version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, once an input is disabled, the browser doesn't look at valid or invalid anymore. The invalid will rule out the other pseudo classes.

Comment: This is disappointing. Stylistic uses notwithstanding, there is no simple way to select all elements which are "candidates for constraint validation" in a particular context. I had been using the selector `:valid, :invalid` which worked quite well until I realized it does not match disabled inputs. As a library developer, this is extremely inconvenient. An exhaustive list of tag name selectors fails to select form-associated custom elements: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#form-associated-custom-element